# HttpClient 4 + HttpPost help with file name encoding

Tags: java, file-io, file-upload, uploading, multifile-uploader

I am trying to upload file to servlet. I am trying to add file name to header and read in on servlet... But in the servlet side the file name (containing cyrillic) I can get is only ??? ?????.wmv. So my question is how to upload file with ciryllic file names correctly?

I use HttpClient 4

```
the code snippet:

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.
                                              PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                                              HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

          String url="testUrl";
          httppost = new HttpPost(url);
          httppost.addHeader(FILE_NAME_HEADER, file.getName());
```

Any useful comment is appreciated :)

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm using Apache Commons FileUpload library to handle file uploads. Here is the [link](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/). Instead of doing Your own, you can use this library. If it doesn't satisfy your needs, you can still work on your own solution.

Comment: Well, I am just trying to use HttpComponents lib :) But I don't get it how to set a proper encoding both client and servlet?

Comment: Is anybody knows how to set headers encoding for HttpClient 4 ?

Comment: Oh, my... Is the HttpClient 4 support encodings into cyrillic etc?

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE mode.
See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-293 for the details

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't find how to use it properly and what it gives? Could you show some snippets please?